# How to write a program to detect process and stop the process in python

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, process, signals

How to identify process that runs main() and kill that process before signal_handler is run?

```
import signal
import sys
import logging
import time
import os

def main():
    print("Main function execution")


    print("Waiting")
    signal.signal(signal.SIGHUP, signal_handler)
    time.sleep(10)
    #How to stop process before signal handler is called?   





def signal_handler(sig, frame):
    logging.basicConfig(filename="DelFIle.log", format='%(asctime)s %(message)s',filemode='w')
    logging.warning(os.getcwd()+"/Del_folder")
    os.remove(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),"/Del_folder/index.txt"))

def Function2():
common resource for main and signal_handler


if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

As the main function may hold resources that signal handler may also be using, i am getting a input/output error because of common resource handling

Comment: I don't quite understand the question, but I suspect you need to use [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) or have one of those two in another file

Comment: Thanks, but i also wrote a snippet wherin i create a seperate Process for this explained in my answer

Comment: Do let me know if any optimization

Comment: good you figured it out, you can mark your answer as accepted :))

Answer (score 0):

```
p=Process(target=Function2,args='')
p.start()
p.join()
```

Adding the following code in functionality in signal_handler helped me create another process to access FUnction2 without vying for resources